# Loaded HTML content not showing in CKEDITOR textarea

Tags: javascript, ckeditor

I have a CKEDITOR loaded on my page, it appears to be working ok.  The contents are being saved to the database in full HTML code in a NVARCHAR(max) SQL Server field.

Contents of the database field after the save

```
<p>this was a test for the full round trip with <a href="http://www.google.com">click here</a> to link to the google</p>

<p>and an additional line here</p>

<p>and one more here</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
```

When I try to load that string into the CKEDITOR from either a database read, or hard coding the value, the contexts are not being shown.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
$('#beb_header').val('');
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData('');

$('#beb_header').val(httpResult[0].header);
CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData("<b>test</b>");
//  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].setData(httpResult[0].message);
//  CKEDITOR.instances['editor1'].insertHTML(httpResult[0].message);
```

The code above appearsto be working, except when I try to load the contents.
The hard coding of the conte, and the two other additional lines, is not displaying the text in the edit area - UNLESS i switch to html code view, then sometimes, the data is shown in the window...  sometimes.

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had to switch to source mode in the config.